# How to take an 'END' alias from case when to calculate another column SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to use the result from a case when to calculate another column

```
CASE WHEN ... END AS TAX,
TAX * 3 AS LALA
FROM...
```

I already tried this:

```
CASE WHEN ... END AS TAX,
(SELECT TAX) * 3 AS LALA
FROM...
```

And this too:

```
CASE WHEN ... END AS TAX,
(SELECT TAX * 3) AS LALA
FROM...
```

There is no problem with the case when, already tried and got the right result.

It says

> Cannot execute query to reader: Ambiguous column name 'TAX'.

I know that I can put the case when again, but there will be a lot of calculations with this result, so it would be really bad to repeat..

Comment: use a CTE or sub-query.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal solution is to use a subquery or CTE for this.  I have a fondness for a third method, using lateral joins:

```
select . . ., v.tax
from . . . outer apply
     (values (case . . . )) v(tax);
```

`v.tax` can then be used in `on` clauses, `where` clauses, multiple times in the `select`, and so on.

You can also have multiple uses of `outer apply`, which makes it easier to build up complex expressions -- without a bunch of indenting for subqueries or CTEs.

Comment: Would be nice if it was possible to put a result from a case when in a decimal variable to use for calculations.

Comment: @ThiagoPereira . . . You can `cast()` the type to whatever type you want in the `values`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the calculation in the outer query:

```
SELECT TAX * 3....... FROM
 (SELECT....select whatever you want...., CASE WHEN ...... END AS TAX 
  FROM...the rest of your query)
```